# No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: spring

It throws NoSuchMethodException while deploying, constructor param is already set in xml config file though. 
What am i missing? Git repo is [here](https://github.com/webyildirim/trafikhaberci) 
Regards

security-configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.trafficalarm.rest.security" />

    <bean id="roleHierarchy"
          class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
        <property name="hierarchy">
            <value>
                ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
                ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="roleVoter" class="com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter">
        <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Access voters -->
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <sec:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>

    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>

</beans>
```

HierachicalJsr250Voter.java

```
package com.trafficalarm.rest.security;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.access.ConfigAttribute;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250SecurityConfig;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250Voter;
import org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchy;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
//import org.springframework.util.Assert;

@Component
public class HierarchicalJsr250Voter extends Jsr250Voter {

    private RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy = null;

    public HierarchicalJsr250Voter(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        //Assert.notNull(roleHierarchy, "RoleHierarchy must not be null");
        this.roleHierarchy = roleHierarchy;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> definition) {
        boolean jsr250AttributeFound = false;

        for (ConfigAttribute attribute : definition) {
            if (Jsr250SecurityConfig.PERMIT_ALL_ATTRIBUTE.equals(attribute)) {
                return ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }

            if (Jsr250SecurityConfig.DENY_ALL_ATTRIBUTE.equals(attribute)) {
                return ACCESS_DENIED;
            }

            if (supports(attribute)) {
                jsr250AttributeFound = true;
                // Attempt to find a matching granted authority
                for (GrantedAuthority authority : extractAuthorities(authentication)) {
                    if (attribute.getAttribute().equals(authority.getAuthority())) {
                        return ACCESS_GRANTED;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return jsr250AttributeFound ? ACCESS_DENIED : ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Authentication authentication) {
        return roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities());
    }
}
```

Exception stacktrace is

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hierarchicalJsr250Voter' defined in file [F:\yildirimBck\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\trafficalarm\WEB-INF\classes\com\trafficalarm\rest\security\HierarchicalJsr250Voter.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 27 more

Apr 07, 2015 6:20:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Comment: Could you post the exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove @Component from your Hierarchical Voter class.

@Component will try to automatically instantiate your class via the component scan and because you haven't @Autowired your dependency, it cannot inject it when it tries to instantiates your class as part of the `<context:component-scan>`. This happens before Spring tries to instantiate your bean via xml...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Spring Security 4, then you should use:

```
<constructor-arg ref="roleVoter"/>
```

For bean accessDecisionManager. So, it should be like:

```
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg ref="roleVoter"/>
</bean>
```